# How to avoid generating .la files generation while cross compiling

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling, libtool, lib

I am trying to cross-compile few software on my computer after cross compiling on my computer, I would like to transfer them (copy and paste) to the other computer. Here is an example of .la files

```
cat liblttng-ust.la
# liblttng-ust.la - a libtool library file
# Generated by libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.6 Debian-2.4.6-2
#
# Please DO NOT delete this file!
# It is necessary for linking the library.

# The name that we can dlopen(3).
dlname='liblttng-ust.so.0'

# Names of this library.
library_names='liblttng-ust.so.0.0.0 liblttng-ust.so.0 liblttng-ust.so'

# The name of the static archive.
old_library=''

# Linker flags that cannot go in dependency_libs.
inherited_linker_flags=' -pthread'

# Libraries that this one depends upon.
dependency_libs=' -L/opt/ursdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot//usr/local/lib /opt/ursdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot//usr/local/lib/liblttng-ust-tracepoint.la -lrt -ldl /opt/ursdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot//usr/local/lib/liburcu-bp.la /opt/ursdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot//usr/local/lib/liburcu-cds.la /opt/ursdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot//usr/local/lib/liburcu-common.la -lpthread'

# Names of additional weak libraries provided by this library
weak_library_names=''

# Version information for liblttng-ust.
current=0
age=0
revision=0

# Is this an already installed library?
installed=yes

# Should we warn about portability when linking against -modules?
shouldnotlink=no

# Files to dlopen/dlpreopen
dlopen=''
dlpreopen=''

# Directory that this library needs to be installed in:
libdir='/opt/ursdk-cxx/i686-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot//usr/local/lib'
```

I see that `libdir & dependency_libs` is absolute path referring to the location on the build computer. I would like to transfer the files on to another computer under `/usr/local/lib`. But the absolute paths would be wrong.

Is there a way to avoid .la their generation while cross-compiling or to avoid absolute path ?

Thanks